# Kohana installation: Logs Directory is not writable. Can't change the root of the directory in the bootstrap.php

Tags: kohana, kohana-3.2

I've just installed kohana in my new project temp.loc 
I type in the browser temp.loc and Environment Tests says:

Cache Directory     The `/work/temp.loc/wwwroot/application/cache/` directory is not writable.

Logs Directory  The `/work/temp.loc/wwwroot/application/logs/` directory is not writable.

I'm trying to change the path `Kohana::$log->attach(new Log_File(APPPATH.'logs'));` in bootstrap.php. BUt, after refreshing the browser, the Environment Test still shows the same path `/work/temp.loc/wwwroot/application/logs/`, the path is not refreshed. Why?

Answer (score 3):

Don't change the location in bootstrap, that isn't needed. The reason you are receiving this error message is probably because those two directories aren't writable. If you are on Mac OSX or a linux environment you need to set those directory permissions to 777 i.e. "chmod 777 cache".  Both are located on your application directory. This is a common issue that I have to resolve every time I install Kohana on a new server.

Comment: wouldn't 777 be insecure? i believe chmod 666 is sufficient according to http://docs.kohanaphp.com/installation

Comment: 777 would probably be insecure but I was only suggesting opening it wide up to see if it fixes his issue. From there you can modify the permissions to something more secure. Thanks for suggesting that @PnarSbiWer